# How to display a vocabulary term list with node count?

Tags: views

How can you display a vocabulary term list with node count?

I have a vocabulary named *books authors*, I want to display a list of the *terms* which includes the total number of nodes next to each term. Like this:

- William Shakespeare (4)
- Xyz (6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the Views module.

1. Create a new View of type Content, filter to all the Content type nodes relevant for your case.
2. Then add a Contextual filter (under `Advanced` in Views) for the Field **Has taxonomy term ID** and configure it to display a Summary:

   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Display a summary**
   `Format` **List**
   `Base path` (you *must* enter the Page path if this isn't the first Page Display in your Views)
   **Display record count with link**
3. If your Taxonomy reference field accepts more than one value (so your nodes can be tagged with more than one term) also check out the options under:

   `More`
   **Allow multiple values**

You will see a list of tags with the count in brackets. You can click on the terms from the Summary and see the relevant results in a separate page.